# Created Date Doesn't Import (D7 to D7)

Tags: nodes, features, importing-exporting

I'm using the Node Export Features module to move over some blogs to another Drupal installation.

Everything seems to transfer but the created date. It resets all nodes to the present date.  How do I preserve the original created date?

Answer (score 1):

In the dashboard, Go to Configuration > Node Export > Reset Values on Import.

...

I love answering my own questions. In fact, every question I've asked here ..well, have been answered by me, and me only. Thanks for all the wonderful help from the (non-existent) Drupal community.